# Given an XmlNode how to remove an item from a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, xmlnode

I have an XMLNode:

```
XmlNode selectedNode;
```

The Treeview is created in XAML:

```
 <TreeView Name="OOB"
<!-- etc.... -->
```

That holds the value of the selected node from a TreeView:

```
 TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch<TreeViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as TreeViewItem;
        if (treeViewItem != null)
        {
            treeViewItem.Focus();
            selectedNode = ((XmlNode)treeViewItem.Header);
//etc...
```

And I wish to delete the selected node. However, when I try this:

```
MainWindow.main.OOB.Items.Remove (MainWindow.SelectedNode);
```

It throws a run-time error:

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify
>   elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

What am I doing wrong? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
if (selectedNode != null)
    selectedNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(selectedNode);
```